Is there a way to deploy a private git submodule to GitHub Pages?
I'm trying to deploy a private GitHub repository that contains a private submodule to GitHub Pages.
The build process works, but since the submodule is private, it can't be cloned (I've tried making it public and it built and deployed just fine). The logs say that it's setting up authentication for cloning submodules, which I would assume means that it should be able to clone private submodules?
I'm fairly new to GitHub actions, so I'm not entirely sure what to do here.
I would like to keep both repositories private if that's at all possible.

It's not possible to do what you want.
Private submodules can't be included:

You can only use submodules that point to public repositories, because the GitHub Pages server cannot access private repositories.

If you want to keep the main repository private, you must use GitHub Pro, GitHub Team, GitHub Enterprise Cloud, or GitHub Enterprise Server:

GitHub Pages is available in public repositories with GitHub Free and GitHub Free for organizations, and in public and private repositories with GitHub Pro, GitHub Team, GitHub Enterprise Cloud, and GitHub Enterprise Server. For more information, see "GitHub's plans."


good to know, thank you (:
I must have missed that in the docs I guess
